# How to sum-up the numbers for the similar groups?

Tags: python

I've two questions. I'm trying to write a script which takes command line arguments and I see I can start the script either using:

```
#!/bin/env python
```

or

```
exec python -x "$0" "$@"
```

What's the difference between those two?

The second question is with scripting. I have an input data-set like this:

```
group_a 5
group_a 7
group_c 6
group_a 8
group_b 8
group_b 4
group_c 7
group_a 8
....
....
```

How can I group together all the similar items and sum up the numbers like this:

```
group_a 28
group_b 12
group_c 13
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Please ask two questions for ... two questions. That way, it's both easier to write/rate answers and to read the whole shebang.

Comment: @phiha, sorry for that. I'll remember in the future. cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little snippet of code lets you summarize your groups as they are read from stdin:

```
import sys

groups = {}
for l in sys.stdin:
    group, value = l.split()
    s = groups.get(group, 0)
    groups[group] = s + int(value)

print groups
```

Comment: thanks for the code. So far, this is the only code that worked with the version of Python I'm using.

Answer (score 5):

This should be two separate questions.

1) The two ways are equivalent. The shebang just marks the program as to be executed by Python, so you don't have to specify it when you run it.

2)

```
import collections
groups = collections.defaultdict(int)

for line in data_set:
    group, value = line.split()
    groups[group] += int(value)
```

A `collections.defaultdict` is a data structure that looks like a dictionary, but if you look up a value which it doesn't contain it automatically creates it with a default value. So this is a neat and concise way of generating the dictionary of group: value on-the-fly.

Comment: @MacUsers: Either you are using Python 2.3 or earlier (in which case you should upgrade; Python has had many improvements since then) or you have a typo in `collections`. (Or something weird is happening: if neither of those is the problem could you post the full error?)

Answer (score 0):

About the second question ....

This is a perfect case to use `groupby` from `itertools` and `yield`. Here it goes my solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
input = [("group_a",5),("group_a",7),("group_c", 6),
("group_a", 8),("group_b", 8),("group_b", 4),("group_c", 7),
("group_a", 8)]

def group(l):
    grouped = groupby(sorted(l), lambda x: x[0])
    for k,n in grouped:
        s = sum(val for name,val in n)
        yield (k,s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for (g,s) in group(input):
        print g,s
```

About your first question ... Both ways are equivalent.

Comment: You don't need the `lambda` in `sorted`, the tuples with be sorted correctly anyways. Nor do you need the `list` in `sum(map(lambda x: x[1],list(n)))` I'd rather write `sum(val for name, val in n)`

Comment: I also can't import groupby from itertools. I get this if I try to do so - `ImportError: cannot import name groupby`

Comment: ummm ... it does work for, what version of python are you running ?

Comment: @msalvadores: this is neat and elegant; unfortunately, it is also significantly less efficient, because you are constructing an entire sorted list in memory in one pass and then using a second pass to group it. `groupby` is a great tool, but sometimes the simple solution is also better.

Comment: I really agree with your comment. But still I think the question in here was a use case to point out the existence of 'groupby' to a non-expert python programmer.

Comment: @msalvadores: I'm using v2.3.4 on this particular machine (RHEL 4.6).

Comment: @MacUsers it is quite an old version. I use 2.6.1 and many users are already migrating to 3 series. I'd definitely go for a newer version of python. Groupby in itertools was new in version 2.4